# Allow shell access from one ip only

Tags: ssh, centos, shell

Is it possible to have root shell access from one particular ip only

I am using centOS. i want that only one user can log in via shell from one ip only

Answer (score 8):

Yes, add the following to sshd_config to enable key only login and to restrict to a particular IP address.

```
AllowUsers root@ip.add.re.ss
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

Comment: I'm assuming the question asker doesn't know how to set up public key authentication yet so they may want "PermitRootLogin yes" instead so they can actually log in with a password.

Answer (score 4):

You could use iptables firewall rules like

```
iptables -I INPUT -s <IP> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j REJECT
```

Answer (score 1):

And another way to do it is with tcp wrappers through /etc/hosts.allow and /etc/hosts.deny -- see my page on this: http://wiki.xdroop.com/space/Linux/Limited+SSH+Access

Answer (score 0):

You can use the suggest line

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

in sshd config. If you then prefix the line of the public key in the authorized_keys file of the root user with

```
from="v.x.y.z" ...
```

then it should have the desired effect.

See the sshd man page, it's explained in the AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT section.

Answer (score -1):

See the ssh documentation:

http://www.ssh.com/support/documentation/online/ssh/adminguide/32/Restricting_User_Logins.html

Comment: CentOS uses OpenSSH, the documentation link you posted is for the commercial SSH.com server. OpenSSH doesn't support all directives mentioned on that page, e. g. `AllowHosts` and `DenyHosts`.

Comment: AllowHosts and DenyHosts can be applied via hosts.allow and hosts.deny if ssh is built with tcpwrappers.